# Redirect a path to a different port using Apache

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost

I am running Apache2.2 on a server, and I would like to set it up so that requests to

```
server/port_path/rest/of#url
```

are handled handled by

```
server:1234/rest/of#url
```

The firewall ensures port 1234 is off limits to the user, and the user should not be aware that requests are ending up on that port.

How should I go about setting this up?